# What will an appended text file look like in Java?

Tags: java, text-files

When in Java, I append text to the end of a text file using FileWriter. Will this new text be on the direct next line of the file or will it leave a line between the old text and new text.

**Presuming my raw data has no new lines and i just rely on the "FileWriter" to append the text.**

This is a simple question but is important in what i am trying to attempt.

**For example:**

Is it this: (no line gap)

```
old data is here
new data is here
```

this: (line gap)

```
old data is here

new data is here
```

or even this: (Turns out this is the correct one)

```
old data is herenew data is here
```

I presume it is either one of these.

Comment: Could you not try this yourself before asking?

Comment: I'd rather know the outcome before writing the code. Plus is would help other people. I do understand where you are coming from however.

Comment: But it all depends _on the code_ you write.

Comment: `"I'd rather know the outcome before writing the code. Plus is would help other people. I do understand where you are coming from however."` -- But yours is a trivial question that will really help no one. The best answer really is for you to try it out yourself. We're no substitute for your Java compiler and JVM.

Comment: Presuming i do not add any new lines in the raw data and just use the function itself to add the data. Will add this to question :)

Comment: @jamesgates1: no, really you should try this out and find out. That's how you learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will this new text be on the direct next line of the file or will it leave a line between the old text and new text.

Answer: Yes.

It will all depend on how you've written your code, and whether or not there's a new line char at the end of the file.

It could be:

```
old datanew data
```

or

```
old data
new data
```

or

```
old data

new data
```

The new data will start writing immediately after the old data ends.

The best answer is as per Sotirios's comment: you should try it out for yourself, experiment with your code. **Play** with your code.

---

**Edit**
Given this:

> Presuming my raw data has no new lines and i just rely on the "FileWriter" to append the text.

Then the answer is

```
old datanew data
```

Comment: You said yes to both statements.

Comment: @jamesgates1: that's right I did, because both statements may be true depending on your file and your code. Read the rest, and try to code it yourself.

Comment: @jamesgates1: see edit. but again, you don't want to cheat yourself out of experimentation. That's where the fun and learning of programming begins.

Answer (score 0):

It fully depends on your implementation and the way you are writing to the file